# Json mutiple dimension unable to read php

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "1421999354744": {
            "article_id": "213123",
            "artfile_status": "",
            "process_starttime": "2015\/01\/23 13:19:14",
            "process": "Validator",
            "process_endtime": "2015\/01\/23 13:19:14",
            "process_status": "COMPLETED",
            "sub_process_name": "",
            "percentage_completed": "100",
            "XML_Validity": "false",
            "process_type": "AUTO"
        }
    },
    {
        "1421999527002": {
            "article_id": "213123",
            "artfile_status": "",
            "process_starttime": "2015\/01\/23 13:22:06",
            "process": "Validator",
            "process_endtime": "2015\/01\/23 13:22:06",
            "process_status": "COMPLETED",
            "sub_process_name": "",
            "percentage_completed": "100",
            "XML_Validity": "false",
            "process_type": "AUTO"
        }
    },
    {
        "1421999580405": {
            "article_id": "213123",
            "artfile_status": "",
            "process_starttime": "2015\/01\/23 13:23:00",
            "process": "Validator",
            "process_endtime": "2015\/01\/23 13:23:00",
            "process_status": "COMPLETED",
            "sub_process_name": "",
            "percentage_completed": "100",
            "XML_Validity": "false",
            "process_type": "AUTO"
        }
    }
]
```

I need to get the values of `article_id` in the above. I've tried to read the multiple dimension but it shows an error.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    $t = $response[$i];
    foreach ($t as $key1 => $value2) {
        echo $t[$j]['article_id'];
        $j++;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

The first array values will be dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And which code did you used to convert it to a array?

Comment: $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($data));

   


        foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
           
            //foreach ($response1 as $response => $value) {
           
          //  foreach ($response2 as $j => $response1) {
               echo ('<pre>');
         // print_r($response[$i]);
   
    $t = $response[$i];
  
        foreach ($t as $key1 => $value2) {
     echo $t[$j]['article_id'];
     $j++;
     }
     
                
            $i++;
        
                

        
                
            }

Comment: Use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28156161/edit) to edit your question and please add the specific error.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need counters at all(*in your case `$i`, `$j`*). You can extract the value from the array by iterating over the array and extracting the data directly from the current value of the iterator:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    // Get the first value of the sub-array array, 
    // which is actually the array you want to extract values from
    $value = current($value);

    // Print out the article id value
    // if your json has been decoded as an array use $value['article_id']
    echo $value->article_id;  
}
```